# Как установить библиотеки в репозиторий GitHub Python?

Tags: python, github, streamlit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как то в гитхабе установить библиотеки, а то я запускаю через streamlit свой код и мне выдает это. Код не буду кидать, потому что проблема в импорте библиотек, а все импорты я делал просто как from import или просто import.

Comment: А при чём тут гитхаб, если на скриншоте streamlit?

Comment: Собственно, в документациии streamlit есть целый раздел про библиотеки https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/deploy_streamlit_app.html#python-dependencies

Comment: Вкратце - в репозиторий нужно добавить файл requirements.txt со списком нужных библиотек